# OS X: alias vs. symlink

Tags: macos, symbolic-link, alias

What is the difference between an "alias" and a symlink on OS X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is answered [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(Mac_OS)) in detail.

And here is a the relevant part from that wikipedia page:

> In Mac OS System 7 and later, an alias
>   is a small file that represents
>   another object in a local, remote, or
>   removable[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(Mac_OS)) file system. It is
>   similar to the Unix symbolic link, but
>   with the added benefit of working even
>   if the target file moves to another
>   location on the same disk (in this
>   case it acts like hard link, but the
>   source and target of the link may be
>   on different filesystems). As a
>   descendant of BSD, Mac OS X supports
>   Unix symbolic links as well.

Comment: It should be noted that aliases do not work as replacements for the objects they represent as well as symlinks do.  For example, i can use a symlink to my Vim configuration folder as a NeoVim configuration folder, but not an alias.  I cannot even inspect the contents of the folder referenced by an alias using `ls <alias name>`.

Comment: In the Wikipedia article: "However, when using the shell command line, Mac OS X aliases are not recognized: for example, you cannot use the `cd` command with the name of an alias file. This is because an alias is implemented as a file on the disk that must be interpreted by Mac API while links are implemented within the filesystem and are thus functional at any level of the OS."